# How to move artifacts between repositories by using REST API?

Tags: rest, api, curl, jfrog-mission-control

Can anybody help me find a way to copy an artifact from one JFROG repository to another by using curl.

I found a way to send file to the repository

> curl -u user:pass -X PUT
>   'http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/test-product/test.txt' -T
>   filetosend.txt

To delete file from repository

> curl -u user:pass -X DELETE
>   'http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/test-product/test.txt'

But I really don't know, how to move file from one repository to another. I do this

> curl -u user:pass -X MOVE
>   'http:(slashes)artifactory:8081/artifactory/test-product/test.txt'
>   'http:(slashes)artifactory:8081/artifactory/test-release/test2.txt'

but it doesn't work.

I have tried different ways, but without any result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the move REST API:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem

The path should be as follows:

curl -u user:pass -X POST 'http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/move/libs-release-local/org/acme?to=/ext-releases-local/org/acme-new&dry=1'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, the command should look like this
curl -u login:password -X MOVE --header 'Destination:http://repo:8081/artifactory/test-release-local/test.txt' 
'http://repo:8081/artifactory/test-snapshot-local/test.txt'

Comment: MOVE command is not allowed with curl